# Elasticsearch Filter 0 hits

Tags: elasticsearch, filter

I am trying to use the filter context in Elasticsearch 6.2.4, but get 0 hits.

Query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "multi_match": {
          "query": "test",
          "fields": ["title", "labels.*", "type"]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "labels.type": "PTR"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The same query without the filter context returns the results I expect it to. Here is one of them:

```
{
  "_index": "events",
  "_type": "event",
  "_id": "5b4853759a04ac31cc3e49ea",
  "_score": 5.3941264,
  "_source": {
    "source": "source1",
    "title": "title1",
    "creation_date": "2018-07-13T07:23:33.983Z",
    "event_date": "2018-07-09T07:53:55.000Z",
    "labels": {
      "tags": "tag1",
      "status": "confirmed",
      "type": "PTR"
    }
  }
}
```

I tried changing **"labels.status": "confirmed"** to **"_source.labels.status": "confirmed"**, which works.

Why does this work for **status** but not for **type** ?

Edit: The search works for **"query": "test"** because **"test"** is part of a **"labels.description"** field (a very long string), which I omitted.

Comment: Your example document contains "source": "source1", which would not be matched by a filter for "source": "events", so that appears to be working correctly.

Comment: My problem turned out not to be where I thought it was: I am trying with "labels.type": "PTR". Thank you for helping me realize that.

Comment: @Jimmy any luck ?

Comment: @TechnocratSid Yes, thank you. I put a more precise comment under your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you getting the results? You don't even have **"test"** in any of the mentioned fields **"fields": ["title", "labels.*", "type"]**?

For your filter context use this:

```
"filter": {
    "term": {
      "labels.type.keyword": "PTR"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works for me. The **"test"** was part of another field of **"labels"** (named **"description"**) which has very long strings.
One thing bugs me though: how come putting **".keyword"** is necessary for some fields (like **"labels.type"**) but not for others (like **"labels.status"**) ?